# Attempting to replace an audio src value on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I'm trying to program a playlist for a site I'm presently working on, and I'm having some issues presently. I've written the script so far and it replaces the default song with a second song, but does not revert back on click.. any suggestions?

The HTML...

```
<audio id="player" src="../audio/small-skeletal.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls autoplay></audio>    

<div id="audio_list" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <div id="track">
        <h2 class="change-song" data-track="http://www.birp.fm/music/playlists/2014/january-2014/027%20-%20Phantogram%20-%20Fall%20In%20Love.mp3">Switch to second song</h2>
        <h2 id="bb" class="change-song" data-track="http://www.logicwebmedia.com/dev/ecb/new-dev/audio/small-skeletal.mp3">Change it back!!</h2>
    </div>
```

```js
$('.change-song').click(function(){
    var song = $('.change-song').data('track');
    $('#player').attr('src', song).attr('autoload', 'auto').attr('autoplay');
});
```

The script only ever returns the first song as the value, and never the second.. how do I fix this?

Comment: Where is that `.wow` class in your html?

Comment: Sorry it was wow on my index page, it should read .change-song. I'll edit the initial post now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `click` function to:

```
$('.change-song').click(function(){
    var song = $( this ).data('track');
    $('#player').attr('src', song).attr('autoload','auto').attr('autoplay');
});
```

`this` is a reference to the element that was clicked.

Comment: @c0nart1st you can select this post as the correct answer, to let other people know.

Comment: still learning the ins and outs! appreciate the help! works perfectly!

Comment: you are welcome! do you still have any doubts about it or got it completely?

Comment: Completely understand!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` as a reference to the clicked `.change-song` element in the click handler. Your current code is selecting both elements at once and when you retrieve the `track` data attribute it only gets it from the first element in the matched set.

```
$('.change-song').click(function(){
    var song = $(this).data('track');
    $('#player').attr('src', song).attr('autoload','auto');
});
```

Comment: thank you! worked perfect! relatively new to writing my own scripts so i appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$('.change-song').data('track');` to `$(this).data('track');` which will give you correct scope.  Sorry for changing song files in the snippet.

```js
$('.change-song').click(function() {
  var song = $(this).data('track');
  $('#player').attr('src', song).attr('autoload', 'auto').attr('autoplay');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttonmit2ani">
  <audio id="player" src="audio/acdc.ogg" controls autoplay></audio>
  <div id="audio_list" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <div id="track">
      <h2 id="aa" class="change-song" data-track="audio/acdc.ogg">Switch to second song</h2>
      <h2 id="bb" class="change-song" data-track="audio/radiohead.ogg">Change it back!!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```